# Why sometimes get 404 not found error sending an Array of objects to an API function from angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I'm getting sometimes 404 not found error when I send a stringified array of javascript objects to an API function.

I have tried changing the method to send the data (POST, UPDATE,...). I have realized if I reduce the number of objects inside the array don't throw 404 error.

In angularjs side the code is:

```
var schedule_to_send = JSON.stringify(my_array_of_objects);
console.log(schedule_to_send);
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: API_URL + 'schedule/update_or_add/',
               params: {
                  schedule_days: schedule_to_send,                 
            },
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                 console.log(response);
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response)
            }
        );
```

1. The endpoint api url is correct, remember it just works sometimes and if the array length is reduced the erro never show up.
2. console.log(schedule_to_send) prints the following:

```
[
   {
      "id":4,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "time_in":"1/1/1970, 08:00:00",
      "time_out":"1/1/1970, 11:00:00",
      "break_time":45,
      "created_at":"2019-06-05 00:41:06",
      "updated_at":"2019-06-05 05:46:08",
      "dates_dim_date":"2019-01-01",
      "day_of_week":"Monday",
      "month":"January",
      "month_day":1
   },
   {
      "id":1,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "time_in":"1/1/1970, 07:00:00",
      "time_out":"1/1/1970, 09:00:00",
      "break_time":30,
      "created_at":"2019-06-05 00:24:20",
      "updated_at":"2019-06-05 05:46:08",
      "dates_dim_date":"2019-01-02",
      "day_of_week":"Tuesday",
      "month":"January",
      "month_day":2
   },
   {
      "id":3,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "time_in":"1/1/1970, 08:00:00",
      "time_out":"1/1/1970, 11:00:00",
      "break_time":45,
      "created_at":"2019-06-05 00:38:01",
      "updated_at":"2019-06-05 05:46:08",
      "dates_dim_date":"2019-12-30",
      "day_of_week":"Wednesday",
      "month":"December",
      "month_day":30
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "day_of_week":"Thursday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "day_of_week":"Friday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "day_of_week":"Saturday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":157,
      "day_of_week":"Sunday"
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "time_in":"1/1/1970, 09:00:00",
      "time_out":"1/1/1970, 10:00:00",
      "break_time":20,
      "created_at":"2019-06-05 00:24:20",
      "updated_at":"2019-06-05 00:41:06",
      "dates_dim_date":"2019-12-30",
      "day_of_week":"Monday",
      "month":"December",
      "month_day":30
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Tuesday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Wednesday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Thursday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Friday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Saturday"
   },
   {
      "id":-1,
      "employee_store_week_id":937,
      "day_of_week":"Sunday"
   }
]
```

3. Laravel controller:

```
    public function updateoradd(Request $request)
    {}
```

4. Api routing:

```
Route::prefix('schedule')->group(function () {
    Route::post('update_or_add', 'ScheduleController@updateoradd');
```

I exspect no error at all and sometimes, I'm getting the following error:

> exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException"
>   file: "D:\MyProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection.php"

**Important note:**
When I reduce the amount of objects in the array to send, this error no occurs, in the other hand, sending exactly the same json showed above (schedule_to_send) sometimes the error happen and sometimes don't and it works just fine.

Comment: The code sends the data in the URL instead of the body of the POST request. It would be wiser to send the data in the body of the POST request.

Comment: You are totally right. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As georgeawg suggested just send the json in the body Post. I have changed the code above to the correct working way.

changed from:

```
 params: {
              schedule_days: schedule_to_send,                 
        },
```

to:

```
  data: {
              schedule_days: schedule_to_send,                 
        },
```